# "Method or data member not found" Access Error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to compare two tables Data with this code:

```
Set rstA = dbs.OpenRecordset("SerialAccount_a")
Set rstB = dbs.OpenRecordset("SerialAccount_b")

While Not rstB.EOF

  serialNumber = rstB.serial
  rstB.Filter = "serial = '" & serial & "'"
  Set rstFiltered = rstB

  Do While Not rstFiltered.EOF

    If rstA.Fields("serial") = rstB.Fields("serial") Then

      If rstA.Fields("accountnumber") <> rstB.Fields("accountnumber") Then

        accountMessage = "... do not match!"
        Debug.Print accountMessage

      ElseIf rstA.Fields("model_number") <> rstB.Fields("model_number") Then

        modelMessage = "... do not match!"
        Debug.Print modelMessage

      End If

    End If
  Wend

Wend
```

When I try to run it, the compiler gives me the error "Method or data member not found" on the line:

```
serialNumber = rstB.serial
```

And I don't understand why, serial is a column in both of those tables. Can someone clue me in as to why this error is popping up?

Comment: You're not even using that variable anywhere.

Comment: I imagine line 7 needs a fix ... will be noticed as soon as line 6 is figured out.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want either `rstB!serial` or `rstB.Fields("serial")`.  The former uses the "bang" operator (`!`) as syntactical sugar for the latter.

When you write `rstB.serial` you are trying to reference the `serial` *property* of the recordset.  But recordset objects have no `serial` property, hence the "Method or data member not found" error you received.

Comment: This is a true story.  See this article to know when you should bang.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/frice/archive/2004/02/18/75685.aspx